# What are the differences between these Array methods

Tags: c#, arrays

These static Array methods have me puzzled. They seem to do the same things. Are they available for older legacy code?

```
Array.IndexOf
Array.FindIndex

Array.LastIndexOf
Array.FindLastIndex
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One accepts an item to match.  The other other accepts a *function* that checks an item and return true if matches, false if it does not.

For example:

```
var x = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
int i = Array.IndexOf(x, 2);
int j = Array.FindIndex(x, a => a == 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3kyey7x5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) takes a predicate.

Two different ways to find 6 in:

```
var nums = new[]{1,3,7,6,5};
```

First even:

```
Array.FindIndex(nums, val=>val % 2 == 0);
```

Value:

```
Array.IndexOf(nums, 6);
```